# Anybody can help? My File manager shows 2.46gigs but there are not many apps in it!!!!why?

Tags: default-applications

My android internal storage is 8 gigs totally. In the storage, it showes 2.46gigs for 'file manager' while there is not a considerable number of apps or any heavy app installed. The file manager app is 22meg but its data size is 2.43gig. I HAVE moved Most of the apps to my sdcard. Moreover, when I unistall an app, there seems to be no difference in its size. It looks like there remain some files in it that I cant see!

What if I uninstall the file manager or clear its data? What would I loose, doing so?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No you wont loose any data rather than its own data . The memory you are seeing can depend on many factors your file manager might also showing the memory consumed by operating system which can take huge amount of memory. Try changing the file manager. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Tnx a lot. I uninstalled the uodates and  It worked without loosing any data. Now i am enjoying not seeing the full storage icon;).  Though solving the problem with my tablet is fascinating to me, I just wonder what was included in the 2gig data of the file manager! Could it be any sign of intrusion into my tablet?

Comment: Some of thee memory is consumed by cache but thats not very much , it must have some files related to android OS. If my answer helped you please rate